# vbs: change codepage

Tags: character-encoding, vbscript, ascii

I have vbs that I run on my desktop.

For some reason, Asc(Chr(148)) returns -32443 in JPN windows.
I don't have this issue on ENG windows.
I found similar issue posted here but it was for .net vb

Is there a way to change codepage of vbs?
I tried chcp on the cmd window i run the script but it didn't do anything.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, your question will be much easier to read if you use more capital letters, and you use the [code span](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) syntax to highlight your code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

I think due to default locale id. Try to set the locale id.

```
'Test the default locale id

WScript.Echo GetLocale 'most likely prints 1041

'Set Locale id

SetLocale 1033 'en-US
WScript.Echo Asc(Chr(148))
```